# findOne NodeJS MongoDB driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have JSON data like you see below in a collection called 'English', for which I'm setting up a REST api with a nodejs app using the MongoDB driver. If I do the following, I get all the JSON data returned in the browser.

```
app.get('/sentences', function (req, res){

     db.collection('english', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {

            res.send(items);
        });
    });

})
```

However, when I try to go to `/sentences/1` to get one record, the app is freezing (the half-moon in the browser tab turns slowly) and there's no error logged.  Is there something wrong with how I'm doing this findOne?

```
app.get('/sentences/:id', function(req,rest){

     var query = { 'question' : req.params.id };
     console.log(query);
     console.log('query');

    db.collection('english', function(err, collection) {

        collection.findOne(query, function(err, item) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(item);
        });
    });
});
```

JSON data

```
[
  {
    "_id": "526c0e21977a67d6966dc763",
    "question": "1",
    "uk": "blah blah blah",
    "us": "blah blah balh"
  },
  {
    "_id": "526c0e21977a67d6966dc764",
    "question": "2",
    "uk": "Tom went outside for a fag. I think he smokes too much!",
    "us": "Tom went outside for a cigarette. I think he smokes too much!"
  },
  {
    "_id": "526c0e21977a67d6966dc765",
    "question": "3",
    "uk": "Do you fancy going to the cinema on Friday?",
    "us": "How about going to the movies on Friday"
  }
]
```

Update

What's happening is that the app is eventually timing out and I get a `No data received` message in the browser.

Answer (score 17):

## nodejs mongodb findOne by id

It is late but will be helpful others.

```
var id = new require('mongodb').ObjectID('58fcf02b1ab5de07e2a1aecb');//req.params.id
db.collection('users').findOne({'_id':id})
 .then(function(doc) {
        if(!doc)
            throw new Error('No record found.');
      console.log(doc);//else case
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem was a typo in one of the arguments (an extra 't' in 'res'). Instead of

```
app.get('/sentences/:id', function(req,rest){
...

res.send(item);
```

should have been

```
app.get('/sentences/:id', function(req,res){ 
...

res.send(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not good  but still will be helpful others.

```
var id = new require('mongodb').ObjectID('58fcf02b1ab5de07e2a1aecb');//req.params.id
db.collection('users').findOne({'_id':id})
 .then(function(doc) {
        if(!doc)
            throw new Error('No record found.');
      console.log(doc);//else case
  });
```

Comment: Why do you copy the existing answer?